# categorical/count independent variable in regression

Tags: regression, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, categorical-data, poisson-regression

I have a variable `snpA` that is the genotype of a particular polyorphism of a patient genomic region. Let's say the genotype can be `A` or `B` and everyone has 2 copies, patients can be `AA`, `AB`, `BB`. I have to insert this variable to understand its effect on a poisson regression model:

```
glm(CAs ~ Age + Exposure + C(snpA), family = poisson(), data = db)
```

I am wondering this is a correct way of considering the effect of `snpA` as the idea is that the `AA` patients are protected, `AB` are at low risk and `BB` are at high risk. Or it would be more advisable to treat it in some continuous or random effect way? It would be advisable to use it as a random effect?

Comment: I don't understand the genetics properly, but the Poisson regression model you give looks fine to me. There are just three levels of snpA, so continuity will quite certainly not help you. Random effects would introduce dependence between the different observations on the same snpA level, which I don't think you want (although this may depend on subject matter knowledge). Another issue is that currently your model doesn't include interactions, which may or may not be OK.

Comment: that is a nice comment @Lewian I didn't think about the dependence introduction with random effects...the "problem" is that ~70% is `AA` and should be at low risk, ~28% is `AB` and should be medium risk and only 1-2% is `BB` and is supposedly at high risk. But probably due to numeric problems for the groups the p is significant only for group `AB` and not `BB`. I was wondering if there was some other method to insert them in such cases...

Comment: You've got to be careful with the interpretation of p-values for individual levels of categorical factors. This depends on how the factor contrasts are coded internally. This can be found out somewhere in the documentation, but in any case the significances refer to some differences between levels rather than raw levels. I'd guess if p-values for AB and BB are given it's AB-AA and BB-AA, but I'm not sure. BB may not be significant due to low sample size with BB.

Comment: In any case if you do something else just because you don't like the p-values (technically meaning that you compute something else conditionally on a p-value being too large for your taste), resulting p-values will be invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you say :

> the effect of snpA as the idea is that the AA patients are protected, AB are at low risk and BB are at high risk.

this implies that you should fit `snpA` as a fixed effect, not random. Besides, since it has only 3 levels and the levels you have are the total population of such levels for that genotype, it would not make much sense to consider it as random.

Your model:

> ```
> glm(CAs ~ Age + Exposure + C(snpA), family = poisson(), data = db)
> ```

seems to be correct, for your research question, however it would be more standard to write it as:

> ```
> glm(CAs ~ Age + Exposure + snpA, family = "poisson", data = db)
> ```

You mention in comments to the question that

> probably due to numeric problems for the groups the p is significant only for group AB and not BB. I was wondering if there was some other method to insert them in such cases.

To answer your research question, "the effect of `snpA`" you should centre your attention on the effect size - ie, the estimates for each level of `snpA`, and not on the p-values. p-values are a function of sample size and if you have a very small sample for some levels then it is quite likely that your study did not have sufficient power in order to detect a "significant" effect. For this reason it is always a good idea to conduct a power analysis prior to collecting data.